# What’s the meaning of the word confuse in Genesis 11: 7?

Tags: genesis, layers-of-meaning

Satan is the author of confusion, and God can’t change, is the same yesterday as today, so how can God be the one confusing the people? Does the author of genesis even know satan existed and was the cause of the people to build the tower to begin with? Wouldn’t it be more accurate to say God came down to see what they were doing and didn’t bless their efforts, therefore confusion and chaos ensued because of their disobedience?

Comment: Jason, I have taken the liberty of editing your question to show exactly which Bible scripture you refer to.  You may find it helpful to take our Tour to see what we look for in well-researched questions: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Please give us the Bible reference to back up "Satan is the author of confusion".  The Bible says Satan is a liar and the father of the lie, but I can't find anything about him being the author of confusion.

Comment: I think some clarification and detail are required in this question. Are you questioning that the word  וְנָבְלָ֥ה ('confound' KJV or 'mingle' YLT or 'confuse' GLT) was uttered by God or are you suggesting that this word was 'misreported' by the author of Genesis ? Or are you just saying that you do not understand the meaning of the text ? Or do you disagree with the conclusions of the major English translations of the Hebrew ?

Comment: Deut 28:20 says that God is the author of confusion in that case.  This question needs clarification.  "The LORD will send on you curses, confusion and rebuke in everything you put your hand ..."  There is no text saying Satan is the author of confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The lemma is בלל, which is vocalized as בָּלַל (*bālǎl*) in the Masoretic text, meaning to confuse, confound or cause difficulty for understanding. The word is also used to describe pouring out of a liquid, or mixing one substance with another, but this meaning doesn't meet the context (see, e.g., Swanson's *Dictionary of Biblical Languages*).  It is translated as συγχέω (*sugcheō*) in the Septuagint, which appears only in Acts in the New Testament and is translated as "confound", "confuse", "stir up" in the KJV.  The Hebrew word appears over 40 times in the Old Testament, but only twice in the sense of "confound" - here in Genesis 11:7 and two verses later:

> *Go to, let us go down, and there confound their language, that they may not understand one another’s speech  ... Therefore is the name of
> it called Babel; because the LORD did there confound the language of
> all the earth: and from thence did the LORD scatter them abroad upon
> the face of all the earth.*

The Masoretic text is pretty clear:  God is the agent and cause of the confusion.

Comment: Concise, yet comprehensive. Up-voted +1,

Comment: Excellent answer. +1.